# How can we quit our gui application safely using multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have created an application in python using tkinter such that when I click the exit button in the file menu it should make the program to exit . For this purpose , I used the concept of multithreading . But , whenever I click on the exit button , it gives me an error

```
#Adding the exit button to the file menu
from modules.threads import Thread_handler as th
file_menu=Menu(menu_bar,tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit",command=lambda : th._quit_thread(self))
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file_menu)


#Creating thread for exit button
def _quit_thread(obj):
    _quit_thread=Thread(target=lambda : ceh._quit(obj))
    _quit_thread.start()

#_quit method binded with the exit button to quit application
def _quit(obj):
    obj.quit()
    obj.destroy()
    exit()
```

I get the following error message :
**RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop**

Answer (score 0):

The Tkinter library is not thread-safe; you should be very careful mixing Tkinter and threads. If you must use threads, then Tkinter calls should *only* be made from the main thread.

As for exiting the application, just use the `destroy()` method of the root window. This exits the `mainloop()`. If you still have any threads running you can `join()` them *after* the `mainloop()`.

This has the added benefit that you can clean up your threads properly while the application window is not visible anymore.